# Livewire image upload 422 unprocessed entity error

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, image, intervention

Please i need help,
Am trying to upload an images using livewire but experiencing 422 (Unprocessable Entity) error when image size is above 2MB.

Am using Wamp server, i have increased memory limit and upload size in php.ini yet the error still persist

Comment: What is the max allowed upload in your PHP.ini?

Comment: max allowed upload is 20

Comment: Does this article help you? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2184513/change-the-maximum-upload-file-size

Comment: I have encountered the same issue, and I had to use: @this.uploadMultiple(), instead of @this.upload().

Answer (score 1):

I experienced something similar, and found a solution. Maybe it can help someone.

Actually, Livewire upload has maximum validation for temporary files by default, we can change it in config/livewire.php:

```
...
    'temporary_file_upload' => [
        'disk' => null,        // Example: 'local', 's3'              Default: 'default'
        'rules' => null,       // Example: ['file', 'mimes:png,jpg']  Default: ['required', 'file', 'max:12288'] (12MB)
        'directory' => null,   // Example: 'tmp'                      Default  'livewire-tmp'
        'middleware' => null,  // Example: 'throttle:5,1'             Default: 'throttle:60,1'
        'preview_mimes' => [   // Supported file types for temporary pre-signed file URLs.
            'png', 'gif', 'bmp', 'svg', 'wav', 'mp4',
            'mov', 'avi', 'wmv', 'mp3', 'm4a',
            'jpg', 'jpeg', 'mpga', 'webp', 'wma',
        ],
        'max_upload_time' => 5, // Max duration (in minutes) before an upload gets invalidated.
    ],
...
```

in rules, we can setting on it:

```
'rules' => ['required', 'file', 'max:52288'],
```

when we leave it null, it will use the condition in the vendor file:

```
    public static function rules()
    {
        $rules = config('livewire.temporary_file_upload.rules');

        if (is_null($rules)) return ['required', 'file', 'max:12288'];

        if (is_array($rules)) return $rules;

        return explode('|', $rules);
    }
```